# creating XML file for tables with multiple indexes and indexes with multiple columns returns duplicate indexes

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am creating an xml file for tables that may have multiple indexes and the indexes may have multiple columns.
My problem is that when I have an index with multiple columns associated with it, the Index is written to the xml file multiple times. (the number of columns).
This is my query:

```
SELECT [IndTbl].IndexName AS "@IndexName", [IndTbl].PrimaryKeyIndex AS "@PrimaryKeyIndex", [IndTbl].IndexDescription AS "@IndexDescription", 
 [IndTbl].PadIndex as "@PadIndex", [IndTbl].StatisticsNoRecompute as "@Statistics_NoRecompute", [IndTbl].IgnoreDupKey as "@IgnoreDupKey", 
 [IndTbl].AllowRowLocks as "@AllowRowLocks", [IndTbl].AllowPageLocks as "@AllowPageLocks",
     (
        SELECT DISTINCT [IndColTbl].IndexColumnName as "@ICName", [IndColTbl].IsDescendingSort as "@IsDescendingSort", [IndColTbl].OrdinalPosition as "@OrdinalPosition"
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT S4.IndexName, IndexColumnName, IsDescendingSort, OrdinalPosition
              FROM #SourceDBObjects S4 JOIN #TableObjectsToAdd T4 ON S4.TableName = T4.TableName AND S4.IndexName = T4.IndexName 
             ) AS [IndColTbl]
         WHERE [IndColTbl].IndexName = [IndTbl].IndexName 
        FOR XML PATH('IndexColumn'),
        TYPE
    )                       
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT T3.TableName, T3.IndexName, S3.PrimaryKeyIndex, IndexDescription, PadIndex, StatisticsNoRecompute, IgnoreDupKey, AllowRowLocks, AllowPageLocks                                
      FROM #SourceDBObjects S3 JOIN #TableObjectsToAdd T3 ON S3.TableName = T3.TableName AND S3.IndexName = T3.IndexName AND T3.IndexName IS NOT NULL ) AS [IndTbl]                     
WHERE [Table].TableName = [IndTbl].TableName
FOR XML PATH('Index'),
TYPE
```

The temporary Table `#SourceDBObjects` has all of the Index data.
The temp table `#TableObjectsToAdd` just has the Index Names to add.

What I need to be able to do is add a `DISTINCT` in the outside query.  But `DISTINCT` is not allowed when using `FOR XML`.

So if the Index has 7 columns associated with the index, the Index will be displayed 7 times in the xml file.

I can't use `TOP 1` because there might be multiple indexes associated with the table.

If I add the IndexColumnName restriction to the IndexColumn subquery (in the SELECT) then I get the Index 7 times with 1 column associated with the index.

How can I limit the Index to display once for multiple columns without using `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found a solution...
I added `GROUP BY` to the outside query and it is limiting the number of times the Index is written to the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a little bit to complicated?

This query will get all the information in one go... You can add more data (e.g. from `sys.stats`) quite easily...

```
SELECT tables.name AS [@name]
      ,tables.object_id AS [@object_id]
      ,(
        SELECT indexes.name AS [@name]
              ,indexes.index_id AS [@id]
              ,(
                SELECT columns.name AS [@name]
                      ,columns.column_id AS [@column_id]
                      ,index_columns.index_column_id AS [@index_column_id]
                      ,index_columns.is_descending_key AS [@is_descending_key]
                FROM sys.index_columns
                    INNER JOIN sys.columns ON index_columns.object_id=columns.object_id AND index_columns.column_id=columns.column_id
                WHERE index_columns.index_id=indexes.index_id
                  AND index_columns.object_id=tables.object_id
                FOR XML PATH('index_column'),TYPE
              ) AS [index_columns]
        FROM sys.indexes
        WHERE indexes.object_id=tables.object_id
        FOR XML PATH('index'),TYPE
      ) AS [indexes]
FROM sys.tables WHERE tables.type='U'
FOR XML PATH('table'),ROOT('DataBase')
```

### UPDATE: Even simpler...

`FOR XML RAW` will put all columns with their names as attributes into the XML (unless you don't specify `ELEMENTS`). With `SELECT *` you'd get all information without much typing...

```
SELECT tables.*
      ,(
        SELECT indexes.*
              ,(
                SELECT columns.name AS column_name
                      ,index_columns.*
                FROM sys.index_columns
                    INNER JOIN sys.columns ON index_columns.object_id=columns.object_id AND index_columns.column_id=columns.column_id
                WHERE index_columns.index_id=indexes.index_id
                  AND index_columns.object_id=tables.object_id
                FOR XML RAW('index_column'),TYPE
              ) AS [index_columns]
        FROM sys.indexes
        WHERE indexes.object_id=tables.object_id
        FOR XML RAW('index'),TYPE
      ) AS [indexes]
FROM sys.tables WHERE tables.type='U'
FOR XML RAW('table'),ROOT('DataBase')
```